# Check if username is already registered in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this JFrame program that just registers users by their full name, username, city, age. I have the checks for the text fields in a method. If you press the register JButton, then it checks if you have entered the information correctly and then creates a new User to an array list.

I need to add a check, that will tell me when I press the Register button if the username exists. I tried making an if statement in my method for checking my text fields right before a new user is created in the area list, but it is just ignored. I tried to make that if statement before the method for the Register button and still nothing. I will paste my Action Listener code below, with my methods.

Edit: posting the method that I use for more clarity.

```
public void fieldChecks()
    {
        if(fullnameField.getText().length() < 6)
        {
            Helpers.showError("Name must have at least 7 characters");
            return;
        }

        if(usernameField.getText().length() < 4)
        {

                Helpers.showError("Username must have at least 4 characters!");
            return;
        }

        if(cityField.getText().length() < 5)
        {
            Helpers.showError("City must have at least 5 characters");
            return;
        }

        if(passwordField.getText().length() < 8)
        {
            Helpers.showError("Name must have at least 8 characters");
            return;
        }

        if(ageField.getText().length() == 0)
        {
            Helpers.showError("Age is a required field!");
            return;
        }
        //check if our boolean is true or false from Helpers class
        if(Helpers.ageCheck(ageField.getText()) == false)
        {
            Helpers.showError("Age must be a whole number!");
            return;
        }

        String fullname = fullnameField.getText();
        String username = usernameField.getText();
        String city = cityField.getText();
        String password = passwordField.getText();
        int age = Integer.parseInt(ageField.getText());
        String sex = " ";
        //check which radio button is selected
        if(maleOption.isSelected())
        {
            sex = "Male";
        }else
            {
                sex = "Female";
            }




            //we have to create a user now by having the above new vars in the user brackets in order of our Class constructor
        User myUser = new User(fullname,username, city, password, sex, age);

        //create the default add function for our arraylist that we added in the vars above
        myUsers.add(myUser);
        Helpers.showConfirmation("User added!");

    }
```

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource() == registerButton)
        {
            //this method checks if my text fields have more 
            //than X charactes typed before it creates a user.
            // This method also adds the new user to my array list 
         //after the checks are complete
            fieldChecks();
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == printButton)
        {
            printUser();
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == searchButton)
        {
            searchUsers();
        }
```

Comment: The code you posted is insufficient to help you find the cause of the problem. Please post at least the code of `fieldChecks()` or `searchUsers()`, whichever one is the method that checks if the user already exists.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I just added the method so that it has more clarity to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I suggest you use a `Set` instead of a `List`. A set is a collection of elements containing no duplicates. The often used implementation, the `HashSet` has a lookup time complexity of *O(1)*, while the `ArrayList` has *O(n)*.

Comment: You have off-by-one errors in your code. `fullnameField.getText().length() < 6` is false for `6`, thus your error is never shown and strings of length 6 are accepted, but your error message says the string should be *at least* 7 characters long. Its a good idea to keep business logic and requirements closely aligned, so inverting the condition and checking for `length >= 7` might be better to avoid such off-by-one errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After:

```
if(usernameField.getText().length() < 4)
    {
        Helpers.showError("Username must have at least 4 characters!");
        return;
    }
```

I would verify if that username is taken with following code

```
if(myUsers.size() > 0)
    {
       for(User user : myUsers)
          {
              if(usernameField.getText() == user.username)
                {
                    Helpers.showError("This username is taken");
                    return;
                }
          }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! I tried this with the for i loop to no avail. I can try the foreach one as it does make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that myUser is an ArrayList of type myUser. You want to override equals method in your myUser class and then call contains. Look up how to @Override equals but here is a short demonstration.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<myUser> users = new ArrayList<>();

    users.add(new myUser("Billy", "xBillx"));

    List<myUser> usersToAdd = new ArrayList<>();
    usersToAdd.add(new myUser("Jill", "jilly"));
    usersToAdd.add(new myUser("Billy", "xBillx"));

    for(myUser newUser : usersToAdd){
        if(!users.contains(newUser)){
            users.add(newUser);
            System.out.println("New user added: " + newUser.fullname);
        } else {
            System.out.println("User already exists " + newUser.fullname);
        }
    }

}


static class myUser{
    final private String fullname;
    final private String username;
    myUser(String fullName, String username){
        this.fullname = fullName;
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object user){
        if(user == this){
            return true;
        }
        if(user instanceof myUser &&
                this.username.equals(((myUser) user).username) &&
                this.fullname.equals(((myUser) user).fullname)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

it prints:

New user added: Jill

User already exists Billy

Edit: made a mistake, you can't compare strings with == in Java

Comment: Hi, yes the ArrayList is of type User. User is my class with a constructor inside and a toString returning a simple message that contains the variables from the constructor. Thanks!